# Image sent via symfony app fosuserbundle registration to Gmail is not showing

Tags: php, symfony, gmail

Please help, I am trying to attach image to Fosuserbundle registeration email template

```
<img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"  src=" 
{{absolute_url(asset('build/images/logo.png'))}}" width="470" height="93" 
alt="Logo" title="Logo" />
```

It is ok on other  mail server except Gmail.
I noticed gmail added  it own link and the image is not showing

https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/q-vSyIKJ61X9Jd07VX0ZZhRVKMHTZn8irsEjkAdX5iTxc2u4dRuB_kQslZrHoN61bz4O55Y4ElWVyLBCkojvDlnpZEWmZ9_738fxiRISRkySVYIxdkR2fEHFOqY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://mysite/build/images/logo.43c7d6e8.png

when I copied http://mysite/build/images/logo.43c7d6e8.png to the browser and checked, I saw the Image.

My first question is that  can "." character break the link?
Second question is that, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to prove with your links?

If the email is not delievered:
Make sure to use SSL to send your email and have the certificate signed for your domain. From: should have your domain, that resolves to your IP from which you are sending and also has a valid SPF record. Google found your E-Mail as a spam. If it is not in your spam folder, google just blocked it. Check your mail log (somewhere in /var/log*mail), it should have a link to google support page with instructions on how to make your mail to get delievered.

No, . can't break a link.

Click on show images in Gmail client to show images.

Comment: you are right, i make use of https and the image shown. thank you